# Appearance customized segmentcontrol odd behavior

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` with a customized appearance, and I believe I have all of the necessary assets to have the correct appearance, and in most cases the appearance is as desired, however when I tap on one of the segments, before releasing, the edges of the segment, right about where the divider image is supposed to be, the appearance suddenly becomes incorrect.  Attached are some screenshots, and here is my code for setting the different images:

```
    UIImage *segmentUnselectedBG = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SegmentUnselectedBG"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 3, 3, 3)];
    UIImage *segmentSelectedBG = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SegmentSelectedBG"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 4, 4, 4)];
    UIImage *segmentDividerNoSelect = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SegmentDividerNoSelect"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 3, 3, 3)];
    UIImage *segmentDividerLeftSelect = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SegmentDividerLeftSelect"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 4, 4, 3)];
    UIImage *segmentDividerRightSelect = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SegmentDividerRightSelect"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 3, 4, 4)];
    UIImage *segmentDividerBothSelect = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SegmentDividerBothSelect"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 4, 4, 4)];

    [self.programControlsSegment setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselectedBG forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.programControlsSegment setBackgroundImage:segmentSelectedBG forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.programControlsSegment setDividerImage:segmentDividerNoSelect forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.programControlsSegment setDividerImage:segmentDividerLeftSelect forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.programControlsSegment setDividerImage:segmentDividerRightSelect forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.programControlsSegment setDividerImage:segmentDividerBothSelect forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Neither segment selected, appearance is correct:

[image: Neither selected - Correct]

Left Segment selected, appearance is correct:

[image: Left selected - Correct]

Left segment selected, and user pressing on the left segment, appearance is incorrect

[image: Left selected and highlighted - Incorrect]

Left segment selected, and user pressing on right segment, appearance is incorrect

[image: Left selected, right highlighted - Incorrect]

Right segment is selected, and user is pressing on left segment, appearance is incorrect

[image: Left highlighted, right selected - Incorrect]

Are there other segment states that I should be setting the divider image for?

EDIT:

This issue seems to be isolated to behavior only in iOS 7.  Prior to this version, there did not seem to be a different state for the segments for when the user is actively pressing down on the segment

Comment: Please double check your image and try this way:http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6. It is fine for me.

Comment: @brianLikeApple After comparing the code given in his segmentedcontrol code compared to mine using a diff tool, the only differences that come up are the names and individual objects used. I am downloading the project and looking at what might be the difference in the assets

Comment: Yes, I am also confused why you get such problem. I also want to know what is going on here. Did you double check your images? Or maybe you can try the images from the link I provided before? If there is no problem, then we can say your images is something wrong : )

Comment: The issue is isolated to iOS 7, when running the tutorial's code in iOS 6.1 the issue does not appear, but it does in iOS 7

Comment: Cool! Thanks! You can answer your question yourself and let us know it.

Comment: @brianLikeApple discovering the problem exists only in iOS 7 does not solve it, it only narrows down what the solution needs to be.